# XCOPY seems to drain redirected input

Tags: testing, batch-file, xcopy

I am trying to write tests for some of my scripts. I am redirecting input from a file that contains input for a specific test case. A few of my scripts use `xcopy`. What I have noticed is that `xcopy` drains the redirected input even though I use the **/Y** option that suppresses prompting for confirmation.

Here's a script to produce this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET some_info=
SET /p some_info=Please provide info:
ECHO.
ECHO Your input was:%some_info%

xcopy /Y some_existing_file.txt some_other_existing_file.txt

SET some_info=
SET /p some_info=Please provide info:
ECHO.
ECHO Your input was:%some_info%

SET some_info=
SET /p some_info=Please provide info:
ECHO.
ECHO Your input was:%some_info%

ENDLOCAL
```

and here's the input:

```
info 1
info 2
info 3
```

Note that files **some_existing_file.txt** and **some_other_existing_file.txt** both exist as their name suggests.

I noticed that `copy` does not drain redirected input but unfortunately I am using the `/EXCLUDE` option of `xcopy` a lot and replacing it with `copy` will cause many changes to my scripts.

Have you noticed this behaviour of `xcopy`? Is there a way to avoid it without making significant changes to my scripts? If you have an alternative suggestion on how to automatically test batch scripts please let me know.

Comment: What is the issue, where the redirection?

Comment: This causes the issue as described `file.bat < input.txt`

Comment: I have my crystal ball forgotten today :(

Comment: @Endoro I apologize, I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works here:

```
<nul xcopy /Y some_existing_file.txt some_other_existing_file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks! It was in front of me and I couldn't see it.